# /etc/resolv.conf kept getting overwritten (how to protect this file)

Tags: networking

On my Linux 17.10 system (previously on 17.04 I didn't have such issue) my `/etc/resolv.conf` file kept getting overwritten to:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I think this is a bug of the NetworkManager. I tried to set this file's owner to root yet it is still getting overwritten from time to time (can't predict when). What is the good way to monitor which process/when was this file modified and how to protect it from getting overwritten?

Comment: It's being overwritten by NetworkManager, as the comment says. Why do you need this? Since you're using NetworkManager, why don't you use it to configure what you want to configure instead of editing the file manually?

Comment: I am not using NetworkManager @terdon how do I use it to configure /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: I don't know, since you haven't explained why you are editing resolv.conf in the first place. Please [edit] your question and explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @terdon I just need to have an actual nameserver instead of 127.0.0.1 to resolve any domain names...I think it is rather obvious. Unless you are asking something else, then idk...

Comment: The `resolv.conf` file can hold various settings, the nameserver is only one of them. NetworkManager is designed to control all this, so if you use it, you need to configure everything through it as suggested in AsenM's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just set up your domain address in the `network manager`, to do this edit `/run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager` file or edit it via graphical interface.